# why is on_raw_reaction_add never activated by a reaction in the discord server

Tags: python, discord.py

I am writing a discord bot that adds your name to a list whenever you react to a certain message. Since these messages can be in the discord for a long time and my discord bot restarts from time to time I decided to use `discord.on_raw_reaction_add(payload)` instead of `discord.on_reaction_add(reaction, user)`. This prevents the function from not activating when a message is not in the cache.

My problem is that, with the same code I had for `discord.on_reaction_add(reaction, user)`, `discord.on_raw_reaction_add(payload)` is not activated.

Here are both simplified examples of my code. If you run it with a token and react to a (new) message you will see that the second sample does not print 'reaction added'.

Working version: (with on_reaction_add)

```
import discord


client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')


@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    print('reaction added')


client.run('TOKEN')
```

Broken version: (with on_raw_reaction_add)
    import discord

```
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')


@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print('reaction added')


client.run('TOKEN')
```

I have tried to add reactions to old messages and new messages. Neither of them gave the expected 'reaction added' response.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the rewrite branch?  `on_raw_reaction_add` is not in the async branch.

Comment: I'm not using the rewrite branch, I am using discord.py version 0.16.12.

Comment: You will need to switch to the rewrite branch to use that event.